# invoking macros in MASM

Tags: assembly, macros, masm

I'm in trouble. MASM macros don't seem to behave like C macros at all. C has a preprocessor which handles the text as a sequence of tokens, and you can put a macro call just anywhere. Not so in MASM it seems. I'm unable to find proper doc for this, but you can't invoke a macro inside a directive, right? Except when it's part of the pars in another macro call? Or when it appers inside a macro def? Are those the only exceptions? Where's the spec/doc?

OK, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
external macro fnames:VARARG
extern stdin:qword,
for fname, <fnames>
    fname&_ptr: qword,
endm
endm

external puts, fgets, printf, srand, rand
```

And I get: 
syntax error : for

It seems already to be interpreting the extern directive and finds the for macro inside which isn't allowed => syntax error.

What the heck can I do? You can split a directive over several lines if you end each line with a comma, right? But if it doesn't interpret macro calls anyway there's no help in it.

I discovered that I can do:

```
external macro fnames:VARARG
extern stdin:qword
for fname, <fnames>
    extern fname&_ptr: qword
endm
endm

external puts, fgets, printf, srand, rand
```

But multiplying the directive isn't always an option. Take the proc directive f.ex. I can't use the proc header for the same proc several times.

Is there a smart solution to this dilemma? Is it possible to use MASM macros to produce a single line of output? I don't know how. Rush to the rescue, all you nerds out there! :) Cheerioh

Comment: One good documentation I found is [this from Randall Hyde](http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/toc.html). See Chapter 8 for MASM directives.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: People who down vote a question are just horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the [`EXTERN` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/extern-masm?view=msvc-160) is

```
EXTERN [[    language-type]] name [[ (altid) ]] : type
       [[, [[language-type]] name [[ (altid) ]] : type ...]]
```

So you can create a one-liner with the [`CATSTR` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/catstr?view=msvc-160) like this:

```
external MACRO fnames:VARARG
  txt textequ <stdin: qword>
  for fname, <fnames>
    txt CATSTR txt, <, &fname&_ptr: qword>
  endm
  extern txt
endm

external puts, fgets, printf, srand, rand
```

**It's output is in one line:**

```
extern stdin: qword, puts_ptr: qword, fgets_ptr: qword, printf_ptr: qword, srand_ptr: qword, rand_ptr: qword
```

Also, if you want to use the output of a `MACRO` as input to another `MACRO`, parameter or expression, you can make use of the [`EXITM` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/exitm?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Great! That solves it. :) I experimented and came up with something very similar to yours. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. Very similar to the above:

```
functions macro fnames:VARARG
local list
list textequ <>
for fname, <fnames>
    list catstr list, <,fname&_ptr: qword>
endm
list substr list, 2
exitm list
endm

extern stdin:qword, functions(puts, fgets, printf, srand, rand)
```

It works! So one can indeed invoke macro functions from inside directives. They must be macro FUNCTIONS, not macro procedures.